# WinForms C# Cefsharp "activate" control

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I've got cefsharp working in my project. There is only one weird thing that I can not figure out. when a url is passed to cefBrowser via a void return the "window" becomes unfocused. This seems to only happen on Youtube.
the project has a section which contains Youtube video links which all work. The page loads correctly but there is a huge "Play" button that must be clicked in order to play the video unless the cefBrowser is clicked first, it doesnt really matter where, even clicking the scroll bar first then loading the url make the videos play correctly. Don't know if this is something simple i am over looking. Even tried setting up a script to click the button but again it does not work unless i click the browser / scroll bar first then run the script.
Any ideas? what over info would benefit to explain the problem better?

the script that "should" click the button:

```
  var script_PlayClick = "document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button ytp-button')[0].click();";
  browser_Main.ExecuteScriptAsync(script_PlayClick);
```

If i switch out the cefBrowser for a WebBrowser the video plays automatically no need to click on anything i can eve have the window minimized and it auto-plays, specially no need to inject any javascript.

thanks for your time. -D.F

Comment: Without an example that reproduces what your seeing it's hard to say exactly. Try something like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/c0d667fc7a482072bcca1ea37d8f99f7b1e3fda9#diff-c5c826de8fb10fb04e8e8922e3c8074b

Comment: If that doesn't work you'll need to provide an example that reproduces the problem, you can fork the `MinimalExample`